# Callback function on a component dispatches an action to Redux, but getting a warning to not do that

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am creating a calendar that is essentially a list of days. As you scroll through the calendar, the `selectedDate` is updated in my state via Redux, using a callback function which will call the prop `onDateDidChange`.

I then check to see if the date did in fact change by comparing it to what is currently stored in the state, and if it's different I then dispatch my action to updated the selected date (the date at the top of the calendar list).

Here is the relevant code:

```
class Calendar extends React.Component {

  onDateDidChange = date => {
    if (!isSameDay(this.props.selectedDate, date)) {
      this.props.onDateDidChange(date)
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <VirtualList
        // other props...
        onItemsRendered={indexes => this.onDateDidChange(dateForIndex(indexes.startIndex))}
      /> 
    )
  }
}

Calendar.propTypes = {
  onDateDidChange: PropTypes.func,
  selectedDate: PropTypes.instanceOf(Date),
}

const mapStateToProps = createStructuredSelector({
  selectedDate: makeSelectSelectedDate(),
})

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    onDateDidChange: date => dispatch(updateSelectedDate(date)),
  }
}

const withConnect = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps,
)

export default compose(withConnect)(Calendar)
```

This actually works, as `selectedDate` is updated in the state as I scroll through the list and it is being updated in other components that map it to their props. The problem is that I get the following warning about updating state/props during rendering:

`warning.js:33 Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within render or another component's constructor). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state; constructor side-effects are an anti-pattern, but can be moved to componentWillMount`

I'm using [react-tiny-virtual-list](https://github.com/clauderic/react-tiny-virtual-list) as my list, specifically I'm using it's **`onItemsRendered`** callback prop to get the current index (the "`selectedDay`") of the list. How can I use this callback function without causing this error?

Comment: It seems that you can't do anything about it because `<VirtualList />` runs `onItemsRendered` callback prop inside its `render` method. It may become a problem, because the code will potentially fall into a loop `dispatch -> update state -> rerender -> dispatch -> update state -> rerender -> .... `

Comment: The thing I'm hung up on is that the callback only happens when the user scrolls on the list, and even then the dispatch will only modify `selectedDate`, which will not trigger a render of `VirtualList` since it's not being used there. I need to keep track of the `selectedDate` for other areas of the app, so I need to dispatch an action as the list is scrolled through.